# Turn off accented characters

Tags: keyboard

When I type `'` then `A` , it types `Á`, instead of simply `'A` . How to disable this feature. It's a pain while programming, as we need to type things like `'example string'` a lot.

Comment: What language keyboard & OS? Doesn't do that on UK English.

Comment: El Capitan and US Keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the proper keyboard layout this won't happen. Proper keyboard layouts are US-english, US-english extended (or ABC Extended in El Capitan) or UK-english.

`'` is a single quote while ` or ´ are accents. The single quote will only yield an `Á` if you have the US International PC keyboard layout active.

[image]

Comment: I figured out the problem. Actually I had set the keyboard to US international instead of US. Now it's working fine.